# How do I get a Nexus 5/~5 inch 1080p phone emulator?

Tags: android

The Android SDK doesn't ship with a device definition for a Nexus 5 emulator (or a ~4.7 inch 1080p phone in general) and I need one. No problem, right? Just copy the Nexus 4 definition and change the resolution to 1080x1920, right?

Well, that gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qpha.png), which obviously isn't right. So what am I doing wrong? I've tried twiddling with the size buckets and density buckets but it's not changing a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of the Android SDK do ship with a device definition for Nexus 5. There is even a really nice nexus 5 emulator skin on github: https://github.com/markusherzog/android-emulator-skin-nexus-5 :-)